# Extending Javascript Date to create a new Date from a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extend Date in order to create a new Date from a string value formatted DD/MM/YYYY. This is the code:

```
Date.prototype.stringToDate = function (date) {

var aDate = date.split("/");
return new Date(aDate[2], (aDate[1] - 1), aDate[0]);    

}
```

When I call it like this:

```
var stringDate1 = "25/12/2019"
var date1 = Date.stringToDate(stringDate1);
```

I get:

TypeError: Date.stringToDate is not a function

Comment: Whats the problem you got?

Comment: Date.stringToDate is not a function...

Comment: By assigning your function on the `prototype`, you're intending that each `Date` *instance* would have a `stringToDate` function. But, your actual intention is to have a *static factory* function that is bound to the `Date` type and not to each instance. Try `Date.stringToDate = function (date) { .. }` instead. Also, consider naming it `Date.fromString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are adding function to protoptype, so it will be available only to instance of Date, not to Date itself.

Here is example with `A` constructor function and 2 functions `someFn` defined on prototype and `someOtherFn` defined on `A` constructor itself.

```js
function A() {
}

A.prototype.someFn = function () {
  console.log('someFn');
};

A.someOtherFn = function () {
  console.log('someOtherFn');
};

console.log('A.someFn', A.someFn);
console.log('A.someOtherFn', A.someOtherFn);

var a = new A();

console.log('a.someFn', a.someFn);
console.log('a.someOtherFn', a.someOtherFn);
```

Second, you don't need such a function, new Date will parse it for you just fine.

```js
console.log(new Date('2016/03/24'));
```

Ok, I see that you want to have dates in format `24/03/2016`, so then you might add some extra function, but I would not define it on Date, extending builtin objects is bad idea in general, cos you never know how interface of such objects might change in future browser version or how your functions might be overridden by third party scripts.

So I would recommend just to declare it as standalone function and use when necessary. It is not big difference between using `stringToDate('24/03/2016')` and `Date.stringToDate('24/03/2016')` if anything, first is shorter.